# Redirect AND rewrite url htaccess

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to rewrite a URL and I don't want existing links to go to the old page (address) any more.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule    ^about-us$    /shop/static_page\.php\?static_page_id=3    [NC,L]
```

This is what my .htaccess file looks like at the moment, and it works fine - although when I add in a normal redirect rule such as:

```
Redirect 301 /shop/static_page.php?static_page_id=3    http://example.com/about-us
```

This doesn't work - it's as if this line doesn't exist. Any ideas please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 things:

1. Ordering of rule is important so have 301 before your internal rewrites
2. Don't mix `mod_alias` rules with `mod_rewrite`

Following code should work for you:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+shop/static_page\.php\?static_page_id=3[\s&] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /about-us? [R=301,L]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteRule ^about-us/?$ /shop/static_page\.php?static_page_id=3 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks for the hints, would you be able to post an example of what it should look like? Many thanks :)